# (AJAX+PHP) Почему не обрабатывается отправка POST запроса по клику на кнопку Delete?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Мой код

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>lab2_ajax</title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="add_form">
        <input type="text" id="nameField" placeholder="Введите имя" required><br>
        <input type="text" id="descriptionField" placeholder="Введите описание" required><br>
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>

    <div id="db_table"></div>



    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(".delItem").click(function(){
            var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log(del_id);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/for_db.php",
                data: {del_id: del_id},
                success: function(html){
                    $("#db_table").html(html);
                } 
            });
        })

        $("#add_form").submit(function(){
            var name = $("#nameField").val();
            var description = $("#descriptionField").val();
            $("#nameField").val('');
            $("#descriptionField").val('');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/for_db.php",
                data: {name: name, description: description},
                success: function(html){
                    $("#db_table").html(html);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })

        

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

for_db.php

```
<?
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8");
    $host = '***';  // Хост
    $user = '***';    // Имя пользователя
    $pass = '***'; // Установленный вами пароль пользователю
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass); // Соединяемся с СУБД
    mysql_select_db("***", $link); // Выбор БД


    if(isset($_POST))
    {
        if( (isset($_POST['name'])) && (isset($_POST['description'])) )
        {

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO chat (name, description) VALUES ('{$_POST['name']}', '{$_POST['description']}')");

            
        } 
        if(isset($_POST['del_id']))
        {
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM chat WHERE id = '{$_POST['del_id']}'");
        }
    }


/* Вывод таблицы из БД */
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat", $link);

    $html = "";

            while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql))#функция вывода таблицы 
            {
                $html = $html."<tr>
                <td> {$result['name']} </td>
                <td> {$result['description']}</td>
                <td> <button class='delItem' id='{$result['id']}'> Delete</button></td></tr>";
            }
            //mysql_free_result($sql);

            echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По динамически добавляемым элементам кликать надо так:

```
$('#db_table').on('click', '.delItem', function(){
  //...
});
```